# Snow Leopard Server doesn't seem to install in a virtual machine on VMWare Fusion 3.0

Tags: vmware-fusion, osx-snow-leopard

I have purchased a new Mac Mini with Snow Leopard Server pre installed.

I plan to use many of its services: Web serving, calendar sharing, mail, file sharing, VPN, etc, for up to 10 users. Problem is, being new to networking, I anticipate this to be a trial and error process.

So I have decided to virtualize Snow Leopard Server under VMWare Fusion 3.0 on my (fairly powerful) iMac, first, do all the trial and error, and once I have gotten it right, setting up the Mac Mini properly.

Problem is, despite Fusion 3.0 working very well with Ubuntu, Windows 7, XP, etc.... the VM gives me an error when trying to install from the Snow Leopard Server disk that came with the Mac Mini: "Mac OS/X cannot be installed on this machine", in this case "this machine" of course being the Fusion 3.0 virtual machine (2 gig RAM, 40 gig HD).

Anybody suggest what I am doing wrong? Isn't Leopard Server supposed to be virtualizable on Apple hardware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running the install disc that came with a server, or the full version. If you are trying to install it by the machine specific version, you will find that it will not work as it's looking for a specific machine ID and will not continue.

I've installed SL Server from the full version DVD without a hitch but was not impressed with the speed.

Comment: Yes Stephen, I am using the install disk that came with the server. I thought that was a full version, but I guess I was mistaken. Anyway you have answered my question. Do you think it might work if I run the VM on the Mini? I'll try it. Thanks.